# git log with exclusive pathspec not matching either case in a binary space

Tags: git

I have this case:

```
$ git log -1 --name-only --oneline 3c4826cc3e
3c4826cc3e foo
path/to/baz.txt

$ git log -1 --oneline 3c4826cc3e -- ':(exclude)./bar.txt'                   
454fe2af84 Merge branch 'baz into mu'

$ git log -1 --oneline 3c4826cc3e -- ./bar.txt
c06c40fed1 Revert "Update bar.txt temporarily"
```

where I expect a commit to match one of two pathspecs as part of a git-log -- either the commit touches or does not touch bar.txt. If a match, then just print the entry corresponding to the SHA specified as an argument to the command. So what I expect is this:

```
$ git log -1 --name-only --oneline 3c4826cc3e
3c4826cc3e foo
path/to/baz.txt

$ git log -1 --oneline 3c4826cc3e -- ':(exclude)./bar.txt'                   
3c4826cc3e updating path/to/baz.txt

$ git log -1 --oneline 3c4826cc3e -- ./bar.txt
c06c40fed1 Revert "Update bar.txt temporarily"
```

where `git log -1 --oneline 3c4826cc3e -- ':(exclude)./bar.txt'`, from what I understand, means, print the first commit reachable from `3c4826cc3e` that does *not* touch ./bar.txt. Essentially, I have a bigger use case where the "exclude" path spec used with git-log is filtering out files a little too aggressively (false-negatives), but is getting most of it right. What am I misunderstanding here?

**EDIT**: I decided to open a ticket for this on git-for-windows issues page: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/4637. More information there.